# PHP preg_replace multiple words

Tags: php

I have a problem when replacing strings with preg_replace.

```
function addClass($search, $string) {

    return preg_replace("/\b($search)\b/", "<div class=mark>$1</div>", $string);

}

$string = "We won again"; 
$result  = addClass("We", $string);

output ---> <div class=mark>We</div> won again
```

I want to make `$search` for multiple strings.

```
$string = "We won again"; 
$result  = addClass(array("We", "again"), $string);

output ---> <div class=mark>We</div> won <div class=mark>again</div>
```

How can I create multiple searches, to put strings in an array?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `or` expresion in regex - `(We|again)`

```
function addClass($search, $string) {
    return preg_replace("/\b(". implode('|', $search) . ")\b/", "<div class=mark>$1</div>", $string);
}
```

And, if you want to save the old syntax, make an array from a single string:

```
function addClass($search, $string) {
    if(! is_array($search)) $search = array($search);
    return preg_replace("/\b(". implode('|', $search) . ")\b/", "<div class=mark>$1</div>", $string);
}
```

[demo](http://ww25.eval.in/588758?subid1=20211120-1750-548c-8d87-07dc65900aa2)

Comment: ahh, my bad. i type "we" instead "We", how to make it case insensitive?

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

The alternative solution using `is_array` and `array_map` functions:

```
function addClass($search, $string) {
    $search = (is_array($search))? array_map(function($v) { return "/\b($v)\b/"; }, $search) : ["/\b($search)\b/"];
    return preg_replace($search, "<div class=mark>$1</div>", $string);
}
```